# iOS Enterprise Distribution - App Icon cannot be seen in spring board for iOS 9 devices

Tags: ios, ios9, ota

I am using Xcode 8.4 to archive my enterprise app and distribute it through OTA. However, the app cannot be seen in spring board in some iOS 9 devices after the users clicked the download button.

After they rebooted the phone.The app icon can be seen in spring board. Does anyone face this problem before? Is it related to plist or other config files?

Many thanks.

More finding:
Actually the device is downloading the application, just the app icon cannot be shown in spring board. And this behaviour only applies to device which hasn't installed the app. Not sure whether this is a iOS 9 feature or bug... I am going to ask Apple support.